# Print the tetration

Tags: code-golf, math, number

> Tetration, represented as \${}^ba\$, is repeated exponentiation. For example, \${}^32\$ is \$2^{2^2}\$, which is \$16\$.

Given two numbers \$a\$ and \$b\$, print \${}^ba\$.

### Test cases

```
1 2 -> 1
2 2 -> 4
5 2 -> 3125
3 3 -> 7625597484987
etc.
```

<sup>Scientific notation is acceptable.</sup>

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: What kind of numbers? Positive integers?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/implement-hyperexponentiation-tetration-without-the-use-of)

Comment: Exponentiation is non-associative. You should include at least one test cade with **b > 2**.

Comment: @Dennis `3 3 -> 7625597484987`

Comment: Can I get the inputs reversed?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Yes

Comment: What are the two downvotes for?

Comment: So 3^3^3 is 3^(3^(3)) and not (3^3)^3 you have to put ()

Comment: @RosLuP No, `3^3^3` automatically means `3^(3^(3))`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations, where it says "Stacked exponents are applied from the top down, i.e., from right to left."

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85847/34718).

Answer (score 16):

## Dyalog APL, 3 bytes

```
*/⍴
```

[TryAPL.](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190*/%u2374%20%u22C4%203%20f%202%20%u22C4%202%20f%203&run)

### Explanation

```
*/⍴  Input: b (LHS), a (RHS)
  ⍴  Create b copies of a
*/   Reduce from right-to-left using exponentation
```

Comment: Hey, somebody who's beating @Dennis! Now that's rare! (; :P

Answer (score 10):

## J, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
^/@#
```

This is literally the definition of tetration.

### Usage

```
   f =: ^/@#
   3 f 2
16
   2 f 1
1
   2 f 2
4
   2 f 5
3125
   4 f 2
65536
```

### Explanation

```
^/@#  Input: b (LHS), a (RHS)
   #  Make b copies of a
^/@   Reduce from right-to-left using exponentation
```

Comment: Ok a^^b is above reversed b^^a...

Comment: @RosLuP Yes, J and APL evaluate from right-to-left, so `2 ^ 2 ^ 2` is evaluated as `2 ^ (2 ^ 2)` and so on

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 19 bytes

```haskell
a%b=iterate(a^)1!!b
```

Iterates exponentiating starting at `1` to produce the list `[1,a,a^a,a^a^a,...]`, then take the `b`'th element.

Same length directly:

```haskell
a%0=1;a%b=a^a%(b-1)
```

Point-free is longer:

```haskell
(!!).(`iterate`1).(^)
```

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:b<1or a**f(a,b-1)
```

Uses the recursive definition.

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
Power@@Table@##&
```

## Explanation

```
Table@##
```

Make b copies of a.

```
Power@@...
```

Exponentiation.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
x*@/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=eCpALw&input=&args=Mw+Mw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=eCpALwrFvDsiw6ciRw&input=&args=MSwgMiwgNQ+MiwgMiwgMg).

#### How it works

```
x*@/  Main link. Arguments: a, b

x     Repeat [a] b times.
 *@/  Reduce the resulting array by exponentation with swapped arguments.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 33 bytes

```
lambda a,b:eval('**'.join([a]*b))
```

This evaluates to an unnamed function, that takes the string representation of a number and a number. For example:

```
>>> f=lambda a,b:eval('**'.join([a]*b))
>>> f('5',2)
3125
>>>
```

If mixing input formats like this does not count, there is also this 38 byte version:

```
lambda a,b:eval('**'.join([str(a)]*b))
```

Comment: What a cool method!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> <s>4</s> 2 bytes

*-2 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

```
Gm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fPff/f2MuYwA) Beats all other answers

```
Gm  # full program
G   # for N in [1, 2, 3, ...,
    # ..., implicit input...
G   # ...minus 1]...
 m  # push...
    # implicit input...
 m  # to the power of...
    # implicit input...
    # (implicit) or top of stack if not first iteration
    # implicit output
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and impressive first answer! I've edited your TIO link so that it includes an example input. Be sure to check out other [recently active](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) challenges as well as our [Tips for golfing in 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/tips-for-golfing-in-05ab1e) page to see if you can shave any bytes off your answer!

Comment: Thanks! I did actually end up checking out that page before submitting this answer :)

Comment: Does `Gm` work?

Comment: @ovs (－‸ლ) of course it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 19 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give numbers on separate lines on STDIN

```
tetration.pl
2
3
^D
```

`tetration.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=eval"$_**"x<>.1
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 39 bytes

Recursive function:

```
f=function(a,b)ifelse(b>0,a^f(a,b-1),1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
[ 1 rot [ dupd ^ ] times ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsJADIb3PsX/AgpWXBRcxcVFnEqF40zxaHt3Jiki0mevQR2aLH@@5E/SOK@Jp8v5eDps4USSF/RO72iJI3Vo@PWtl80QvYYUBV1QYtcJMpPqK3OICqHHQNGTURd4wcm3pNgVxbuAxRsrlBj/upzpzUyvLcdinCqb5qSocBvyDVfU0NDb7tpa8nTZgB3PSchc4@/vfW9c1Pl2Cd@R4@kD)

*-3 thanks to @Bubbler*

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsJADIb3PsX/AgpWXBRcxcVFnEqF40zxaHt3Jiki0mevQR2aLH@@5E/SOK@Jp8v5eDps4USSF/RO72iJI3Vo@PWtl80QvYYUBV1QYtcJMpPqK3OICqHHQNGTURd4wcm3pNgVxbuAxRsrlBj/upzpzUyvLcdinCqb5qSocBvyDVfU0NDb7tpa8nTZgB3PSchc4@/vfW9c1Pl2Cd@R4@kD).

Answer (score 2):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 11 bytes

```
__2:':1[^]`
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=X18yOic6MVteXWA&input=NQoy)

This is just "straightforward" exponentiation in a loop.

```
__2:':1[^]`
__              take two values as input (x and y)
  2:'           duplicate y and send one copy to the control stack
     :          make y copies of x
      1         push 1 as the initial value
       [ ]      loop y times
        ^       exponentiate
          `     print result
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 24 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>b?a**f(a,b-1):1
```

The ES6 version is 33 bytes:

```
f=(a,b)=>b?Math.pow(a,f(a,b-1)):1
```

Comment: Save 1 byte: `f=a=>b=>b?a**f(a,b-1):1`

Comment: @programmer5000 no, the function call would have to be `f(a)(b-1)` inside, adding 1 byte and cancelling out the effect.

Comment: @ophact You're right, but that's a 4-year-old comment... However, you can *really* get [-3 bytes by calling only the inner function](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP9HWLs02ydYuyT5RSytNI0nXUNPK8L@mhpGmhomm5n8A).

Answer (score 2):

## dc, <s>35</s> 29 bytes:

```
?dsdsa?[ldla^sa1-d1<b]dsbxlap
```

Here is my first complete program in `dc`.

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
d=a=argument0;for(c=1;c<b;c++)d=power(a,d)return d
```

Comment: This is my 300th answer :o

Comment: GameMaker wtf? lol

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, and while I'm at it I'll take off 2 bytes for you.

Comment: Lol, nice. =) Have my +1, seems simple enough and I understand it.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 51 Bytes

```
for($b=$p=$argv[1];++$i<$argv[2];)$p=$b**$p;echo$p;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 40 bytes

```
map{$a=$ARGV[0]**$a}0..$ARGV[1];print$a;
```

Accepts two integers as input to the function and outputs the result

Comment: Use `pop` to get `$ARGV[1]`, then use `"@ARGV"` to get `$ARGV[0]`. Use `say` instead of `print` (option `-M5.010` or `-E` is free). But still, `ARGV` is terribly long. A `-p` program almost always wins

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
n`ⁿ)`Y
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=bmDigb8pYFk&input=Mwoz)

Input is taken as `b\na` (`\n` is a newline)

Explanation:

```
n`ⁿ)`Y
n       a copies of b
 `ⁿ)`Y  while stack changes between each call (fixed-point combinator):
  ⁿ       pow
   )      move top of stack to bottom (for right-associativity)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 9 bytes

```
q~)*{\#}*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX4pKntcI30q&input=WzUgMl0)

#### Explanation

```
q~          e# Take input (array) and evaluate
  )         e# Pull off last element
   *        e# Array with the first element repeated as many times as the second
    {  }*   e# Reduce array by this function
     \#     e# Swap, power
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 21 bytes

```
f\@@[#0?^#1f#1-#0 1?1
```

Uses the recursive approach. Usage:

```
f\@@[#0?^#1f#1-#0 1?1];f 2 3
```

## Bonus solution, 22 bytes

```
@@:^ -#0 1(genc ^#1)#1
```

A slightly unconventional approach. Usage:

```
t\@@+>#[^;#1]tk -#0 1rpt#1;t 2 3
```

More readable:

```
@@
  iget
    - #0 1
    (genc ^#1) #1
```

Assuming `a^^b`:

Generates an infinite list of tetrated `a`; for `a=2`, this list would look something like `[2 4 16 65536...]`. Then indexes at `b-1` because Wonder is zero-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry) `-nii`, 14 bytes

```
{}{{}({})}{{}}
```

[Try it online!](https://bubbler-4.github.io/Flurry/#!ewB9AHsAewB9ACgAewB9ACkAfQB7AHsAfQB9AA==#MgAgADQA##bgBpAGkA#MQAwADAAMAAwAA==)

Takes two numbers `a b` from stdin, and outputs as the return value.

#### How it works

It works basically like [xnor's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97021/78410): repeat `(a^)` `b` times to 1. `a` is left on the stack, so that it can be referenced in each iteration.

```haskell
// In Church numeral, x a → a^x
main = b power_of_a 1

power_of_a = \x. x a
           = \x. x (push pop)  // assumes a is on the top of the stack,
                               // pops and takes its value and pushes it back
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 9 bytes

```
~])*{\?}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy5WU6s6xr5W6/9/YwVjAA)

```
~]          # Put a and b in an array
  )         # Remove b from the array
   *        # Make b copies of a
    {  }*   # Execute this block for each number in the array
     \?     # Exponentiation
```

Just `{?}` would be `(3^3)^3` instead of `3^(3^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

This is lyxal's solution

```
‹(⁰e
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%80%B9%28%E2%81%B0e&inputs=3%0A3&header=&footer=)

```
‹(⁰e
‹     Decrement b
 (  ) For loop (second parentheses is implicit) using b-1
  ⁰   Push a
   e  And raise it to the power of the accumulator (initially a)
```

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to lyxal

```
ʁ•⁽eḭ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%81%E2%80%A2%E2%81%BDe%E1%B8%AD&inputs=3%0A%5B3%5D&header=&footer=)

This one is a worse solution. `a` is inputted as a singleton list.

```
ʁ•λe;ḭ
ʁ      Make a range [0,b) (only the length of the range matters (b))
 •     Reshape [a] to that (make a list of b a's)
     ḭ Reduce from the right
  λe;  using exponentiation
```

Comment: [5 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%81%E2%80%A2%E2%81%BDe%E1%B8%AD&inputs=3%0A%5B3%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [4 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%80%B9%28%E2%81%B0e&inputs=3%0A3&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s><sup>38</sup></s> <s><sup>26</sup></s> 37 bytes

*Thanks to @9214 for telling me about the `loop` command for -12 bytes.*

*+11 bytes to fix invalidities brought out by @Bubbler.*

```
func[a b][x: a loop b - 1[x: a ** x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85OlEhKTa6wkohUSEnP79AIUlBV8EQwtfSUqiIjf1fUJSZV6KQpmCoYMQFYxshsU2R2MYKxv8B)

Comment: Tip: you can simplify it down to 27 with `loop`.

Comment: @9214 Thanks, that is exactly the command I needed, and apparently, it returns a value, so I can even simplify it down to 26 bytes!

Comment: Gah, I said 27 because of the missed space after `1`...

Comment: Is this answer valid without `func[a b]` part? Because it looks like, say, omitting `lambda a,b:` part in Python, which is invalid (makes the answer a snippet with `a` and `b` hardcoded).

Comment: @Bubbler Fixed. I think I understand now how function submissions work. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
(*/#)/#
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs9LQ0lfW1Ffm4kqLNrI2igVSxhDKBMYzjgUAo1gI6w==)

Takes two inputs in the order of `[hyperexponent; base]` and returns the result.

K does not have exponentiation built-in, so I simulate `n^m` with "product `*/` of m copies `#` of n" instead. Tetration is basically the same, in the sense that it is a fold by exponentiation. K's fold is left to right, and `*/#` accepts `[exponent; base]`, so the direction of exponentiation is correctly `y^(y^(y^...))`.

Although it does not use exponentiation built-in, it fails to solve [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5562/78410) because `4^(4^4)` is way too big to handle with built-in integer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
u^QGE1
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%5EQGE1&input=5%0A2&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
          (implicit: input a to Q)
     1    Start from 1.
u   E     b times,
 ^GQ      raise the previous number to power a.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
nnDI1-[;]N.
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nnDI1-%5B%3B%5DN%2E&input=3%203)

#### Explanation

```
nn             Read two integers from input
  D            Pop top of stack and duplicate next element that many times
   I1-         Push length of stack, minus 1
      [        Pop top of stack and repeat for loop that many times
       ;       Pop b, a and push a^b
        ]      Close for loop
         N.    Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 51 bytes

```
(define ans 1)(for((i b))(set! ans(expt a ans)))ans
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f a b)
  (define ans 1)
  (for((i b))
    (set! ans
          (expt a ans)))
  ans)
```

Testing:

```
(f 1 2)
(f 2 2)
(f 5 2)
(f 3 3)
```

Output:

```
1
4
3125
7625597484987
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 45 bytes

```
Seq.fill(_:Int)(_:Double)reduceRight math.pow
```

Ungolfed:

```
(a:Int,b:Double)=>Seq.fill(a)(b).reduceRight(math.pow)
```

Build a sequence of `a`s with `b` elements, and apply `math.pow` from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 19 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
A
For(C,2,B
A^Ans
End
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>71</s> 57 bytes

```
double c(int a,int b){return b>0?Math.pow(a,c(a,b-1)):1;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/CKCu1E)

```
class M{
  static double c(int a, int b){
    return b > 0
            ? Math.pow(a, c(a, b-1))
            :1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(1, 2));
    System.out.println(c(2, 2));
    System.out.println(c(5, 2));
    System.out.println(c(3, 3));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.0
4.0
3125.0
7.625597484987E12
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 50 bytes

```c
double t(int x,int n){return n?pow(x,t(x,n-1)):1;}
```

Straightforward from the definition of [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Answer (score 0):

**Axiom 70 bytes**

```
l(a,b)==(local i;i:=1;r:=a;repeat(if i>=b then break;r:=a^r;i:=i+1);r)
```

this less golfed

```
l(a,b)==
  local i
  i:=1;r:=a;repeat(if i>=b then break;r:=a^r;i:=i+1)
  r


(3) ->  [l(1,2),l(2,2),l(5,2),l(3,3),l(4,3)]

     (3)
     [1, 4, 3125, 7625597484987,
      13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030_
       0735469768018742981669034276900318581864860508537538828119465699464336490_
       06084096
       ]
                                                   Type: List PositiveInteger
```

Comment: 8 bytes would be reduced if `local i;` could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 50 bytes

(within the bounds of bash integer data type)

**Golfed**

```
E() { echo $(($(printf "$1**%.0s" `seq 1 $2`)1));}
```

**Explanation**

Build expression with printf, e.g. E 2 5:

```
  2**2**2**2**2**1
```

then use bash built-in arithmetic expansion to compute the result

**Test**

```
E 1 2
1

E 2 2
4

E 5 2
3125

E 3 3
7625597484987
```

Answer (score 0):

### Powershell, 68 Bytes

```
filter p ($a){[math]::Pow($a,$_)};iex (,$args[0]*$args[1]-join"|p ")
```

This is the shortest of the three approaches I tried, not that great overall though, i'm 100% sure there's a shorter approach but the few things I tried somehow ended up with slightly more bytes.

```
PS C:\++\golf> (1,2),(2,2),(5,2),(3,3) | % {.\sqsq $_[0] $_[1]}
1
4
3125
7625597484987
```

Sadly Powershell has no built-in `^` or `**` operator, or it would be a clean 32/33 byte answer, i.e.

`iex (,$args[0]*$args[1]-join"^")`

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 56 bytes

```
(fn[a b](last(take a(iterate #(apply *(repeat % b))b))))
```

Maybe there is a shorter way via `apply comp`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 27 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>(b<2)?a:a^f(a,b-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z/NViNRJ0nT1k4jycZI0z7RKjEuDSSia6j5v6AoM69EI03DWMdYU/M/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ọƲ@
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQiU4RCVDNiVCMiU0MCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTIlMkMlMjAxJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEEyJTJDJTIwMiUyMC0lM0UlMjA0JTBBMiUyQyUyMDUlMjAtJTNFJTIwMzEyNSUwQTMlMkMlMjAzJTIwLSUzRSUyMDc2MjU1OTc0ODQ5ODcmZmxhZ3M9Q2V0)

##### Explanation

```python
ọƲ@  # Implicit input
ọ    # Repeat [a] b times
 Ʋ   # Reduce the list by:
  @  #  Swapped exponentiation
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 16 bytes

```
{[**] $^a xx$^b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OlpLK1ZBJS5RoaJCJS6p9n9xYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWaQo1KfK2SQlp@kYKNoYKRnY6CjRGEMoVQxgrGdv8B)

`$^a` and `$^b` are the arguments to this anonymous function.  `$^a xx $^b` is a list of the first argument replicated a number of times given by the second argument.  `[**]` reduces that list with the exponentiation operator.  The reduction respects the right-associativity of the operator.